# my app break after updating rubygems and bundler

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, bundler

i had an application created with rubygems package manager 1.8.24 and bundler 1.2.4, today i update my rubygems and bundler to the latest verstion with these commands :

```
gem update --system
```

and

```
gem update bundler
```

now my version of rubygem is **2.0.3** and my version of bundler is **1.3.5**

but when i return to my app and i try to run server , it gives errors :

```
/home/mody/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385@global/gems/bundler-1.2.4/lib/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:187:in `stub_source_index170': uninitialized constant Gem::SourceIndex (NameError)
from /home/mody/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385@global/gems/bundler-1.2.4/lib/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:353:in `stub_rubygems'
from /home/mody/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385@global/gems/bundler-1.2.4/lib/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:250:in `replace_entrypoints'
from /home/mody/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385@global/gems/bundler-1.2.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:14:in `setup'
from /home/mody/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385@global/gems/bundler-1.2.4/lib/bundler.rb:116:in `setup'
from /home/mody/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385@global/gems/rubygems-bundler-1.1.0/lib/rubygems-bundler/noexec.rb:77:in `setup'
from /home/mody/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385@global/gems/rubygems-bundler-1.1.0/lib/rubygems-bundler/noexec.rb:89:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/mody/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:110:in `require'
from /home/mody/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:110:in `rescue in require'
from /home/mody/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:35:in `require'
from /home/mody/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:9:in `<main>'
```

i'm going to my app home directory then i'm trying this command :

```
bundle -v
```

it show me :

```
Bundler is not compatible with Rubygems 2.0.
Please upgrade to Bundler 1.3 or higher.
```

i understand that bundler version's of my app is not compatible with my rubygems

how i can fix this error

**note** all my gems are in the default gemset.

i have anothoer question about difference between `gem install bundler` and `gem update bundler` ? because i see some people do **gem install bundler to update bundler**

thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
gem install bundler --pre
```

Run this command

Comment: when i want to run this command ? in my app home directory ? then what means of --pre option and this command in general ?

Comment: You need to update to the 'prerelease' of bundler, run it from your app directory